# Isolate multiple projects into a single git repository

Tags: git

I'm actually facing a complicated issue. I have one git repository who have to contain back-office and front-office project. I am constrained by this structure and cannot change it for submodules. What I'm trying to do is to isolate one project from other:

When I'm working on back and having to commit I would like to ignore front project file tree and and vice versa.

What I did from now is having a global gitignore file for the repository and one gitignore per project.
Knowing childrens gitignore files root dir is the directory of the containing folder i tried to exclude both projects in the global .gitignore and reinclude them on every .gitignore child to allow me to track files for the current project I'm working on, without success.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, git already provides the possibility to commit just a subtree of your repository: through the [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

if you look at the [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) documentation, you will see that you can specify a pathspec to limit the subtree you want to commit. In your situation, something like this:

```
git commit -m "commit for the back-office only" back/
```

A couple of improvements:

- configure local aliases to commit to the back/front-office, like

  ```
  git config alias.commitback 'commit back/'
  ```

  and call it like any normal `git` command:

  ```
  git commitback -m "your commit message"
  ```
- Just to be sure, you could create a pre-commit hook to verify that what you are about to commit come from the back-office or the front-office, but not from both. This script certainly fails if you use the `git commit` without any pathspec and you have staged changes from both subtrees.

---

EDIT:
@torek pointed out an interesting flaw of this approach:

> This does not only commit the sub-tree. Instead, it uses `git commit --only` (that's the default, vs `--include`) to: (1) make a new temporary index matching `HEAD`; (2) run `git add` on the temporary index to add
> back/; (3) commit the result. The resulting commit is what you'd get
> if you had done `git reset` followed by `git add back/`: i.e., a full
> snapshot of every file, as always. (Note the final index state is
> potentially quite different though.)

I checked just now and he is right: with pathspec, git completely ignores the current index for the subtree you want to commit, unless we add untracked files, that stay untracked even after `git commit pathspec`.

To solve this, you can use `git stash push` with the option `--keep-index` in order to move to the stash only those changes that you have not staged yet. so the new workflow would be:

- `git stash push --keep-index` (`-u` should not be necessary)
- `git commit pathspec`
- `git stash pop`

Generally, `--keep-index` is used for [partial commits](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-Testingpartialcommits), but seems to work perfectly in this case.
However, in this way, I think you cannot add any further option to `git commit` in the alias above.

Comment: This does not only commit the sub-tree. Instead, it uses `git commit --only` (that's the default, vs `--include`) to: (1) make a new temporary index matching `HEAD`; (2) run `git add` on the *temporary* index to add `back/`; (3) commit the result. The resulting commit is what you'd get if you had done `git reset` followed by `git add back/`: i.e., a full snapshot of every file, as always. (Note the final index state is potentially quite different though.) That may well be good enough for the OP's needs, but it's not quite what they asked for....